# Is destructured es6 export a valid syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am wondering about the following syntax:

```
export const { foo, bar } = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: 234,
}
```

I can't find it described in any es2015 [documentation](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#an-overview-of-the-es6-module-syntax), but it is [supported by Babel's es2015 preset](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=%0A%0Aexport%20const%20%7B%20foo%2C%20bar%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20foo%3A%20123%2C%0A%20%20bar%3A%20234%2C%0A%7D).

Is this syntax truly standard, as babel seems to think? Out of standard?

Comment: See [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on MDN.

Comment: For ES6 documentation, your best bet is MDN, although for a more complete (albeit denser) read you can see: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing it, but I don't see where this covers module exports? (reply to @abhishekkannojia)

Comment: @noahnu - MDN doesn't address this case. the ECMA documentation refers to "export _Declaration_" as a valid syntax. But I'm not sure if _Declaration_ includes destructuring assignment.

Comment: I believe it's using "export *VariableStatement*"

Comment: It's standard, yes, but I hope nobody uses this. One really should do `export const foo = 123; export const bar = 234;` or `export const foo = 123, bar = 234;`

Comment: @Bergi the real use case is something like: export const { foo, bar } = returnsFooBarObject();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things going on here.

```
export const { foo, bar } = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: 234,
};
```

is equivalent to

```
const { foo, bar } = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: 234,
};

// Export all the names in the variable declaration.
export { foo as foo, bar as bar };
```

`export` can be used on many declarations and will export whatever variables are created by that declaration.

Then this is simplified further if you don't understand destructuring, it is essentially

```
const _tmp = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: 234,
};
const foo = _tmp.foo,
      bar = _tmp.bar;

// Export all the names in the variable declaration.
export { foo as foo, bar as bar };
```